# Prevent Docker Compose from creating separate network

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, docker, docker-compose

I discovered that [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) places containers in a separate network when using [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2) of their YAML syntax. This makes linking with existing containers difficult.

Is there a way to prevent this, and revert to the behavior of [version 1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-1), without actually reverting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this, and revert to the behavior of version 1, without actually reverting?

In your service configuration, specify:

```
network_mode: bridge
```

For example:

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build: web
    network_mode: bridge
```